# Woocommerce custom start ratings

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce, sass

As I almost customized each template of woocommerce, I have decided to disable the woocommerce stylesheet. Now I'm trying to style stars ratings to match woocommerce default..
Givern the default form markup how can style it to match woocommerce default?

```css
/*sass styles*/
.stars{
    a{
        position: relative;
        height: 1em;
        width: 1em;
        text-indent: -999em;
        display: inline-block;
        text-decoration: none;
        &::before{
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 1em;
            height: 1em;
            line-height: 1;
            font-family: WooCommerce;
            content: '\e021';
            text-indent: 0;
            color: $main-color;
        }
        &:hover{
            &::before{
                content: '\e020';
            }
        }
        &.selected{
            &::before{
                content: '\e020';
            }
        }
        &.active{
            &::before{
                content: '\e020';
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

```html
// html markup
<div class="comment-form-rating">
  <label for="rating">Your rating</label>
  <p class="stars">
    <span>
      <a class="star-1" href="#">1</a>
      <a class="star-2" href="#">2</a>
      <a class="star-3" href="#">3</a>
      <a class="star-4" href="#">4</a>
      <a class="star-5" href="#">5</a>
    </span>
  </p>
  <select name="rating" id="rating" required="" style="display: none;">
    <option value="">Rate…</option>
    <option value="5">Perfect</option>
    <option value="4">Good</option>
    <option value="3">Average</option>
    <option value="2">Not that bad</option>
    <option value="1">Very poor</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Have a look at a page using the default CSS, and mimic it

Comment: I guess this is what you are looking for: https://css-tricks.com/star-ratings/

Comment: Thank you for response!. I just mimic the woocommerce default and it worked